# Response caching using Retrofit 2.x

Tags: android, http, caching, retrofit2, etag

Can somebody explain me how does Retrofit 2.x caches HTTP responses along with HTTP response headers. I'm new to Retrofit and had used Google's official library volley earlier for HTTP response caching by making use of ETAG and Last-Modified time but I'm not finding any posts on caching using Retrofit.

Comment: Look at okhttp3 articles it, OkHttp have caching and other stuff . Retrofit is just comfy way to use okhttp

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit doesn't cache the response like Volley. For more details refer to [this](http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-volley-vs-retrofit-better-approach/)

Comment: Thanks for time but the blog you mentioned is last updated on April 2015.  I see many updates in Retrofit 2.0 but not finding response caching part

Comment: Some features are still not implemented in it based the structure of this library cache and Image downloading are examples of that.